# Different shipping rates to countries inside the UK

Tags: cartthrob, shipping

Our client has asked us to help setup different shipping rates for Northern Ireland in CartThrob. This poses a problem because Northern Ireland is classed as part of the UK and so it does not have a separate country code to match shipping rates to.

At present on our site we use the [Multi Location Manager](https://cartthrob.com/site/product_detail/multi-location-manager) to set 'By Location - Price Threshold' for countries outside of the UK and 'Customer Selectable Rates' for everyone inside the UK, which offers Standard Delivery and Next Day Delivery options.

We would like to be able to offer Standard Delivery and Next Day Delivery options to Northern Ireland customers but at different rates to elsewhere in the UK.

Ideally, some kind of Table Rate would probably be best suited, so that we can match Northern Ireland postcodes (which all start with 'BT').

However we need to ensure we can still offer the Customer Selectable Rates to Northern Ireland customers.

Answer (score 1):

There are currently no available CartThrob shipping plugins that do what you require. You would need to create a custom shipping plugin.

Comment: Thanks Barrett. It's a shame that when using the Shipping Zip field for By Location - Price Threshold doesn't go from BT*. Instead we would have to enter BT1, BT2, BT3 etc to match all postcodes.